# Where to place/find the systemjs.config.js file in an angularJS2 project?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2 and trying to use the ng2-datetime-picker in my project. Now after installing the ng2-datetime-picker package when I run the project got an **404 error stating ng2-datetime-picker not found**, after going through some blogs I came to know that I had to add the configuration in the systemjs.config.js file but when I went through my project I cannot see any systemjs.config.js file in my project. so my question is,

1. where does the systemjs.config.js file exist?
2. Is the below code meant to be the systemjs.config.js file

   System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
3. If it is, then how can I add map and packages to this file

   map[‘ng2-datetime-picker'] = 'node_modules/ng2-datetime-picker/dist';
    packages[‘ng2-datetime-picker'] = { main: 'ng2-datetime-picker.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js’ }
   **update 1**

This is my systemjs.config.js file

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app : 'ScriptsApp', // 'dist',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'ng2-datetime-picker': 'npm:ng2-datetime-picker'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: { main: './boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
            rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'ng2-datetime-picker': { main: 'ng2-datetime-picker.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

and the added reference in the index.js file is

```
 <!-- Polyfills for older browsers -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

this is the error i am getting after adding the systemjs.config.js file and the refrence in the index.html file
[image]

Comment: are you using `angular-cli` ?

Comment: no,i am not using angular-cli, sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a "systemjs.config.js" file and load it from index.html, like a regular script:

```
 <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

Make sure you also include System.JS before the config script:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

The following script loads the first module:

```
System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
```

By default (according to your systemjs.config.js), SystemJS will look for app.js or app/main.js.

In your systemjs.config.js file, you want to map the node package to a path where there is an index.js or package.json, which indicates where the module is located. The module should be compatible with your module loader that you intend to use: AMD, UMD, CommonJS, SystemJS, es6 etc

The following should work in your systemjs.config.js file:

```
'paths': {
    'npm:':'node_modules/'
},

'map': {
     'ng2-datetime-picker': 'npm:ng2-datetime-picker'
      ...
},
'packages':  {
     'ng2-datetime-picker': 'dist/ng2-datetime-picker.umd.js'
 }
```

Or, you could map the UMD file directly:

```
'paths': {
    'npm:':'node_modules/'
},

'map': {
     'ng2-datetime-picker': 'npm:ng2-datetime-picker/dist/ng2-datetime-picker.umd.js'
      ...
}
```

The following will only work with CommonJS/AMD/SystemJS as index.js uses the 'require' syntax:

```
'paths': {
    'npm:':'node_modules/'
 },

'map': {
     'ng2-datetime-picker': 'npm:ng2-datetime-picker'
      ...
},
'packages':  {
     'ng2-datetime-picker': 'dist/index.js'
 }
```

EDIT

This should work:

```
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: { main: 'boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-datetime-picker': { main: 'dist/ng2-datetime-picker.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
```

Comment: i have added the systemjs.config.js next to the system.src.js file as you have mentioned, but now i get a 404 error of /ScriptsApp/boot.js. I am updating my systemjs.config.js file in my question for your refremce... thank you

Comment: I don't think you updated your question. The 'main' path should have 'dist' in it.

Comment: what do you mean by main path? is it the object in the systemjs.config.js file?thannx

Comment: in my last edit, I have  'ng2-datetime-picker': { main: '*dist*/ng2-datetime-picker.umd.js', but in your question, you don't

Answer (score 2):

For those, who are looking for `systemjs.config.js` content. It will be something similar to this, You can configure it as per your requirements.

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

And your index.html will look like : (Take care the order of .js file)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Angular 2 App!</title>

    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>body { padding: 50px 0; }</style>

    <!-- js -->
    <!-- load the dependencies -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

    <!-- load our angular app with systemjs -->
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
```