# Module build failed: ng serve angular

Tags: angular

I keep running into this error despite upgrading the entire node_modules. I've also tried deleting `node_modules`. I am new to angular and I am not very sure what this error is trying to tell me. I dont have other error messages. This is the only message I am receiving. Any guidance is appreciated!

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2/dist/directive.ts
Module build failed: Error: Path\user-app\node_module
s\jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2\dist\directive.ts is not part of the compilation output
. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (Path\us
er-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:629:23)
    at plugin.done.then (Path\user-app\node_modules\@
ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./node_modules/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2/dist/index.js 10:18-40
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: What is jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2? Are you trying to use bootstrap?

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr it appears to be a dependency from a template i installed. dependencies - it's you love them or hate them.

Comment: Refer, this may help-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219493/where-to-place-find-the-systemjs-config-js-file-in-an-angularjs2-project        and this also https://www.npmjs.com/package/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr yeah I tried those. I think I am just going to redo everything.